# TableLayout Without XML, Nothing Appears on Screen

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I was trying to create `TableLayout` Without XML, Nothing Appears on Screen. Below is my code. Please let me know what is the mistake?

**Code :**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act);
        TableLayout tlMain =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlMain);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        tlMain.setLayoutParams(lp);


        tlMain.setStretchAllColumns(true);  
        tlMain.setShrinkAllColumns(true); 


        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rowLp.weight=1;

        TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {   
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                TextView number2 = new TextView(this);
                number2.setTextColor(color.black);               
                number2.setText(String.valueOf(i));                
                tableRow.addView(number2,cellLp);
                tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);               
            }
            tlMain.addView(tableRow,rowLp);              
        }
        setContentView(tlMain);    
    }
```

Comment: can you post R.layout.act??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tlMain"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    

       

</TableLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    This is How it started Working.

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);  
     table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
     table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
     TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
     rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
     TableRow.LayoutParams trparams = new   TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rowTitle.setLayoutParams(trparams); 
    rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); 
    TableRow rowDayLabels = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow rowAmounts = new TableRow(this);
    TextView empty = new TextView(this);
    empty.setText("Empty");
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    table.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    title.setText("WikiCode");
    rowTitle.addView(title);
    rowTitle.addView(empty);
    table.addView(rowTitle);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {   
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(trparams);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            TextView number2 = new TextView(this);
            number2.setLayoutParams(trparams);               
            number2.setText("check"+i);                
            tableRow.addView(number2);
            tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);               
        }
        table.addView(tableRow);              
    }


    setContentView(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

to

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

also don't call:

```
setContentView(tlMain);
```

Assuming that you have a table layout in `R.layout.act`

Try to change:

```
 TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to:

```
 TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

My guess is that you have a table row with width Wrap_content and a Textview inside it with width fill_parent.

This are contradictory statements and android is not able to draw it.

Comment: Same Result, White Screen. :(

Comment: Still, It didnt draw the table :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `TableLayout` without using `layout-xml`  then

Try with this

```
 TableLayout tlMain = new TableLayout(this);
```

Instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.act);
TableLayout tlMain =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlMain);
```

Comment: I first tried as you suggested. Then I tried by adding a table layout with id tlMain. Same results in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
setContentView(tlMain);
```

use

```
mainlayout.addView(tlMain);
```

where mainlayout could be linear or relative layout or any other container, which wrap your table.

Comment: I ve got this error
 "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addView(View) from the type ViewGroup"

Comment: You code already using this  `TableLayout tlMain =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlMain);` which means your already added tablelayout in your view. You don't need to use `setContentView(tlMain); ` and `mainlayout.addView(tlMain);`. Try without anything

Comment: Yeah I did, got the same result